# NGINX only have SSL for www but not non-www. How to redirect non-www & no SSL to www with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I used certbot to get make my website https but it only allowed me to choose the www version because when I would choose the non-www version certbot would give an error:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: sample.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2606:4700:3036::6815:ea3: Invalid response from http://sample.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dxI1o6dBbQC4S2VougcOTSfSrG18GUqpiqYh7WvAT3c: 522
```

So I was only able to get it for [www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com). But now when I try to access the site without www I get an `'Invalid SSL certificate'` from the browser. I want to redirect non-www to www after days I can't figure it out. Below is the nginx config file.

```
server {
        server_name www.sample.com;

        client_max_body_size 55M;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sample.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sample.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.sample.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.sample.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here what I tried:
1.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sample.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

2. 

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name sample.com;
        return 301 https://www.sample.com$request_uri;
    }
```

3. 

```
server {
    if ($host = www.sample.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = sample.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.sample.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I had a lot more but those were the most memorable ones IDK what to do anymore.

EDIT: So I fixed the problem by running certbot again and getting ssl for both domains. For some reason it allowed me to do it now. But if I still didn't have SSL for non-www is the only option still to get SSL for it?